# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in file on line 128

Tags: php, syntax

Hi So this is the code: 
Its a page to display my available tables in the database in a drop-down, then display the results in the table. The actual code to do so (in the middle) works perfectly on its own, but when I try to add my template around it I get errors...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" >
<meta name="description" content="" >
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<title>SNYSB Archive</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" >
<!-- Location of javascript. -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js" ></script>
</head>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    <!-- KEEP THIS BIT [ITS FORMATTING] --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end #header -->
    <div id="menu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="Hpage.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Register.php">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end #menu -->
    <div id="page">
    <div id="page-bgtop">
    <div id="page-bgbtm">
    <div id="content">
            <div class="post">
            <div class="post-bgtop">
            <div class="post-bgbtm">
<h1 class="title">PUT HEADING HERE!</h1>
                <div class="entry">
                    <p class="Body">
<?php
$dbname = 'snysbarchive';
$conn= mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'usbw');
if (!$conn) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if (mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn))
{
?>
    <form method="post" action="new 2.php">
    <select name="tables">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    ?>    
    <?php
        echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Show">
</form>
<?php
//mysql_free_result($result);
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['tables']))
{
    $tbl=$_POST['tables'];
    //echo $_POST['tables']."<br />";
    $query="SELECT * from $tbl";
    $res=mysql_query($query);
    echo $query;
    if ($res)
    {
    ?>
    <table border="1">
    <?php
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";        
            echo "</tr>";
        } ?>
    </table>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
</div>
</div>
            </div>
            </div>

        <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end #content -->
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
                    <p>Welcome to SNYSBs archive!
                       </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>SNYSB</h2>
                    <p>
            <a href="Contact.php">Contact Us!</a>
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end #sidebar -->
        <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #page -->
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2008 Sitename.com. All rights reserved. Design by <a href="http://www.freecsstemplates.org/">Free CSS Templates</a>.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- end #footer -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It keeps saying unexpected end but I am not sure how to fix it?

```
Error Message:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in file on line 128
```

Thanks

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket.

Comment: @user1262534 dont forget to accept your answer by clicking on the tick!

Comment: It won't let me do so yet as i'm a new member, but thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: @AisRuss no prob, welcome to the team.

Comment: You may need to change `<?` to `<?php`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have not selected your database with correct braces around the function.

Comment: Why is this answer marked as a solution? It will be more fair to select @Ing answer, which it's better answer and was answered before.

Comment: In this case that is not the issue. Listing tables of a database doesn't require select database statement.

Answer (score 12):

This may also occur when mixing short and normal open tags when the server does not support [`short-open-tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) (`<?` instead of `<?php`), even though this wasn't the case in your code.

```
<?php

$showHeader = true;

if ($showHeader) {
?>
<h1>Hello, World!</h1>
<?
}
?>
```

Note that the closing bracket will not be registered if the server doesn't support the `<?` open tag.

Comment: At this point, most servers have that enabled by default. However, Xampp intentionally disabled it. Your answer saved me quite a bit of time trying to figure out what was wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You have saved a life

Answer (score 11):

Line 50: `if (mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn))` has an opening bracket and not a closing one.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to change `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: this saved my day...my dev server had allow_short_tags but my production server didn't...

Answer (score 0):

you forget to close this block with a `}` :

```
if (mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn))
{
?>
```

Try this code :

```
<?php
$dbname = 'snysbarchive';
$conn= mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'usbw');
if (!$conn) {
    echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if (mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn))
{
?>
    <form method="post" action="new 2.php">
    <select name="tables">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Show">
    </form>
<?php
}

//mysql_free_result($result);
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['tables']))
{
    $tbl=$_POST['tables'];
    //echo $_POST['tables']."<br />";
    $query="SELECT * from $tbl";
    $res=mysql_query($query);
    echo $query;
    if ($res)
    {
    ?>
    <table border="1">
    <?php
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";        
            echo "</tr>";
        } 
    ?>
    </table>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a '}' so following if block is not closed.

```
if (mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn))
{
```

By adding a } in Line #91 your code will be worked.

But always try to write much cleaner code by following best practices.