# Woocommerce template Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php, wordpress

I just tried to add something at the bottom of my functions.php file and now I get this error and I can't open my website anymore.

The error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /public_html/wp-content/themes/propulsion/functions.php on line 456.

When I download the file with filezilla I even can't see line 456, there are only 437 lines.

I have pasted my php here:

http://pastebin.com/kcq74k34

I already tried replacing it with the default functions.php but I keep getting this error. I tried deleting my functions.php and still the same error. why ?

Comment: clearly you aren't downloading/uploading the correct file then. try again.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that PHP hit the end of the file before it was expecting it. You are far from the only person to run into this error message and come to us for help.

- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in file on line 128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658172/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-in-file-on-line-128)
- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file - line 59](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886113/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-line-59?rq=1)
- [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in functions.php on line 90](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487666/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-in-functions-php-on-line-90?rq=1)
- [fatal error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947524/fatal-error-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-in?rq=1)

### Common causes include

- Mixing short and long tags when only long tags (ie `<?php` and not `<?`) are supported. This is not your problem.
- Opening but not closing a brace like `{` or `(` or some such. I have been right thought your code and cannot find an example of this.
- An FTP error. Try adding `?>` to the end of the file (or just a few empty lines). This might be a fix. You might also like to check that the FTP transfer is taking place in ASCII mode or Binary.